# Emulating Qualcomm Snapdragon

Tags: android-emulator, emulation, qemu

I am trying to boot an Android image that was designed for Qualcomm Snapdragon 210 (MSM8909 SoC) on my computer.

I have all the necessery files (initrd, zImage, system.img, boot.img).
What is the best way to do so? qemu did not work for me.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: Still no solution...

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot more to modelling a full SoC like a Snapdragon than just having an ARM emulation. You would need to model the peripheral devices as well as a board that incorporates the chip with additional devices. As far as I'm aware the only Android images that work under emulation specifically target emulation targets (goldfish, ranchu and now cuttlefish). I'm not aware of any work to model the Snapdragon or any of the boards that use it in QEMU.